# Does swagger-jaxrs @ApiModelProperty AllowableValues work with "range[x,y]"?

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

I haven't been able to get the following to produce any results:

```
@ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "range[0,8]", required = true)
private String myfield;
```

This works:

```
@ApiModelProperty(allowableValues = "Email, Post", required = true)
private String multiValField;
```

and produces (in the UI):

```
multiValField(string) = ['Email' or ' Post']
```

I may be misreading the documentation, this is from the javadocs in ApiModelProperty:

> To set a range of values, start the value with "range", and
>   surrounding by square brackets include the minimum and maximum values.
>   For example: range[1, 5].  To set a minimum/maximum value, use
>   the same format for range but use "infinity" or "-infinity" as the
>   second value. For example, range[1, infinity] means the
>   minimum allowable value of this parameter is 1.

I can't find any examples of people doing this, though it seems like it would be common.  I did find this in modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/test/scala/testresources/ResourceWithReturnTypes.java which is an @ApiParam, but I wasn't able to get this working either on my GET endpoint.

```
@ApiParam(value = "sample param data", required = true, 
allowableValues = "range[0,10]")
@DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("id") String id) {
```

Does anyone have some version of this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger-core projects holds a set of samples in it. The usage of `range` is exhibited in both `@ApiParam` and `@ApiModelProperty`.

The `@ApiModelProperty` can be seen here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/scala-oauth-authorization-server/src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/model/Pet.scala#L30.

The `@ApiParam` can be seen here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/java-jaxrs/src/main/java/com/wordnik/swagger/sample/resource/PetStoreResource.java#L42.

All samples contain simple details on how to run them locally, and they output with `minimum` and `maximum` values as expected.

Comment: ok, I'll check out the scala-oauth-authorization-server project now and see if I can spot any differences.  Thanks Ron.

Comment: I ran the project, I can confirm it is in the api-docs output {"id":{"type":"integer","format":"int64","description":"unique identifier for the pet","minimum":"0.0","maximum":"100.0"}, but I don't see the results in the swagger-ui. "id (integer): unique identifier for the pet", is that a known issue?

Comment: It was probably never implemented. The validation in Swagger 2.0 is far more extensive, so there's a better chance it'll be introduced in the new swagger-ui. Feel free to open an issue about it.

Comment: thank Ron.  I might be in a catch-22 there.  Do you know of any examples of the range working in swagger-jaxrs 2.0?  I did a test project using 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT https://github.com/javatestcase/RestEasy/tree/RestEasyVersion2 , and I don't see the "minimum":"0.0","maximum" output into swagger.json.  If that doesn't work, and swagger-ui 1.0 doesn't work, I might be stuck on both fronts.

Comment: It looks like it's not yet implemented in swagger-core 1.5. It's best to open an issue about it.

Comment: thanks again Ron, seems the swagger-ui issue for 2.0 was just created 7 days ago - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/808

Comment: I was referring to swagger-core 1.5 not producing it though.

Comment: Yes, I just added an issue for that as well https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/818

Comment: 2020 any help ?